# mediawiki - assign Ctrl-S to save page (edit mode)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mediawiki

Mediawiki:

I'd like to change the key combination alt-shift-s to be ctrl-s for saving a page that is currently being edited.

Comment: Note that Alt+Shift+S is the browser's default implementation for the `accesskey` attribute on elements. Also Alt+Shift is what Firefox makes of it, IE uses just Alt. So generally, you'll need to do that by other means than it is done now.

Comment: Google Docs lets me use Ctrl-S -- That's what I'm after. Any tips? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have knowledge on JavaScript, you could look into something like http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/126/how-to-create-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-javascript/ or http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/ as a starting point. (If you'd like you could do a Google search for `javascript detect ctrl-s`)

From there you could do something like simulate a click event on the save button.

Comment: URL Broken... Can you describe a bit more here for future references?

Answer (score 0):

```
#IfWinActive, [part of tab name]
^s::!+s
#IfWinActive
```

In the [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) scripting language :)